# Splitting a file of sentences by line and using findall to extract certain parameters

Tags: python, findall

I'm attempting to go through a file of sentences and pull out the capitals line by line within those sentences.

Here is the data file I am working on:

```
the dog_SUBJ bit_VERB the cat_OBJ
the man_SUBJ ran_VERB
the cat_SUBJ ate_VERB the cheese_OBJ
```

Essentially, I want the program to output 'SUBJ', 'VERB' and 'OBJ' for each line. However, for each line with the script I am working on now, the output is all of the capitals in the file on each line, as opposed to just the capitals in that line.

Here is the output I am getting now:

Line 0: `the dog_SUBJ bit_VERB the cat_OBJ`

```
['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ']
```

Line 1: `the man_SUBJ ran_VERB`

```
['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ']
```

Line 2: `the cat_SUBJ ate_VERB the cheese_OBJ`

```
['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ']
```

For example, I want the program to output for line 0, 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ', as that what is in that line.

Here is the script I am working with at the minute:

```
import re, sys
f = open('findallEX.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
ii=0

for l in lines:
    sys.stdout.write('line %s: %s' %(ii, l))
    ii = ii + 1
    results = []
    for i in lines:
        results += re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', i)
```

Thanks!

Comment: That gives this output: line 0: the dog_SUBJ bit_VERB the cat_OBJ
[['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ'], ['SUBJ', 'VERB'], ['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ']] but on each line? So it might still be going through all the lines

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating the list of lines twice for no apparent reason. Try this:

```
import re
with open('findallEX.txt', 'r') as f:

    for ii, line in enumerate(f):
        print 'line %s: %s' % (ii, line)
        results = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', line)
        print results
```

(I've also made things a bit more Pythonic; you should use a context manager to open files (with `with`), and manually controlling loop variables should be avoided.)

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
with open('text.txt') as f:
    print [''.join(g) for k, g in 
           groupby(chain.from_iterable(f), key=str.isupper) if k]
```

---

```
['SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'SUBJ', 'VERB', 'OBJ']
```